# wrapfig: overlap with text after equation in next paragraph

Tags: wrapfigure

In the following MWE, the text below the equation
overlap with the wrapfigure. If I remove the equation, it works.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[20]{O}{0.5\linewidth}
\rule{0.9\linewidth}{0.75\linewidth}
\caption{Dummy figure.}
\end{wrapfigure}
Short paragraph

\begin{equation}
        a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I tried already several tricks described in related questions (like `\leavevmode` after the wrapfigure,
setting the line count explicitly etc.), but they do not help.

Inserting a paragraph break directly after the equation, that can be undone by negative vertical space, bypass the problem,
but this seems to be not the correct solution to me.

Comment: Try not leaving empty lines before the equation environment.

Comment: @campa Thanks, this also solves/bypasses the problem.